# Reading in view return values ​from the controller AJAX / ASP.NET Update NEW

Tags: javascript, asp.net, json, ajax, asp.net-core

- called by selectbox go into function 'getDepAndMan()',
- there is a value taken from the selectbox (works)
- calls functions in the controller 'GetDepartmentAndManager' (works)
- controller returns value  (works)

  > {Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable<<>f__AnonymousType6<'string, string>>}
  >
  > Result View: [0] { UserDepartament = "there is value here / string", UserManager = "there is value here / string" }
- should go back to ajax and call 'succes: function (employee data)' (works)
- should assign values ​​to the fields  (doesn't work)
- show an alert (work)
- show alert with values (doesn't work, show an alert with: undefined undefined)

**View:**

```
@(Html
     .DevExtreme()
     .SelectBox()
     .DataSource(d => d
          .Mvc()
      )
     .OnValueChanged("getDepAndMan")
  )
 @(Html.DevExtreme().TextBox()
      .ID("Id_department")
      .ReadOnly(true)
  )
 @(Html.DevExtreme().TextBox()
      .ID("Id_manager")
      .ReadOnly(true)
  )

<script type="text/javascript">

    function getDepAndMan() {


        var userId = {
           nazwaValueId: $("#idName").dxSelectBox("instance").option("value")
        };

        $.ajax({

            url: "@Url.Action("GetDepartmentAndManager", "Uzytkownicy")",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {"userId": JSON.stringify(userId)},
            cache: false,
            success: function (danePracownika) {
                  $("#Id_department")
                     .dxTextBox("instance")
                     .option("value", danePracownika.UserDepartament);
                 $("#Id_manager")
                     .dxTextBox("instance")
                    .option("value", danePracownika.UserManager);

                alert(danePracownika.UserDepartament + " " + danePracownika.UserManager);
            },
            failure: function (error) {
                alert(error);

            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetDepartmentAndManager(string userId) 
{

  dynamic serializer = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary>(userId);

            var IdCzlowieka = serializer["nazwaValueId"];

            int IntIdCzlowieka = Convert.ToInt32(IdCzlowieka);

            var danePracownika = _uzytkownicyContext.Uzytkownicy.Where(x => x.Id == IntIdCzlowieka).Select(s => new
            {
                UserDepartament = s.Departament,
                UserManager = s.ManagerLogin

            });


   return Json(danePracownika);
}
```

return : //

> [0] { UserDepartament = "there is value here / string", UserManager = "there is value here / string" }
>   [image]

EDIT

**The question is, what's wrong with the code, why it doesn't work for me?**

.

Comment: It is unclear what you are actually asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see that in Your `GetDepartmentAndManager` You are not using Your passed parameter `userID`:

```
var danePracownika = ... .Where(x => x.Id == IntIdCzlowieka)...
```

should be `Where(x => x.Id == userId)` instead.

The next thing that came to me is the value You are acctualy getting inside the controller action; based on the JS code I would say that this is not the ID of the employee what You are passing but the stringified object `{ "nazwaValueId": ... }` that in the best case would be handled by the server and You will get the raw string as a value of `userId` (unless You have defined a `IModelBinder` class that would handle conversion from stringified `{ "nazwaValueId": ... }` to the value of that field - more on that You can find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/aspnet/core/mvc/advanced/custom-model-binding?view=aspnetcore-3.1)).

Oh any by the way - please try to avoid mixing languages. I have a friend in the company which was forced to work with the german project and all their code was written in German - You would DEFINETLY won't be happy working with it. But if this a project made only by PL for PL, that is some kind of acceptable approach I assume.

Also I highly advice You to not use HTTP `POST` method for getting data. To make long story short there is a convention that `GET` requests are for getting the data and You can call it as many times You like without affecting the state (było takie mądre słowo na to, ale nie pamiętam ;)) and `POST` is for saving/modifing data and should always redirect to `GET` method on return. You can read more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp).

EDIT:

Ok, for some reason I have found that the call in the current form is sending data not as a body but as a form. I don't know, I don't use jQuery. But here is the reqest:
[image]

so I changed the signature of the action to

```cs
public ActionResult GetDepartmentAndManager([FromForm]string userId)
```

to get is started working. Maybe on Your side it is just working fine, I don't know. But what I have found is that while sending the responce to the client we end up with... this:
[image]

so as You can see either Ajax or server changed the JSON keys to be kebabCase not PascalCase and that's why You are getting undefined values. Because properties You arereading do not exists. Just check it out: `alert(danePracownika.userDepartament + " " + danePracownika.userManager);`

UPDATE:

I checked it, it was not server's fault:
[image]

Comment: and how do you unpack the sent information from the controller in Ajax?
because it doesn't work properly for me :(

Comment: @krolPodGora You can directly pass the value of the SelectBox `var userId = $("#idName").dxSelectBox("instance").option("value")` and then `data: {"userId": userId}`

Comment: but I need the other side, from the controller to Ajax , I can't read the data there